# getting ng-animate to work

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

This is an ng-animate noob question. I looked at the example at [angularjs.org](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow#usage_animations) and copied the html and css into my project. I added ngAnimate to the dependencies of my app. But it's not working. Upon (un)checking, the correct div is displayed, but no animation.

I tried adding 'ngAnimate' to the dependencies of my Controller, but then I get this error: [http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.11/$injector/unpr?p0=ngAnimateProvider%20%3C-%20ngAnimate](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.11/%24injector/unpr?p0=ngAnimateProvider%20%3C-%20ngAnimate)

i notice that the example app has ng-app="ngAnimate" in the body tag, I thought adding ngAnimate to my dependencies would do the same.

Can anyone help?

here is the fiddle : [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/CosmicAcidGuru/Up26b/) (unfortunatley angularjs not working)

```
var app = angular.module('my', [
  'ngAnimate',
  'my.controllers'
]);

var controllers = app.module('my.controllers', []);
controllers.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.checked = true;
});
```

Comment: Show the code (or preferably create a fiddle).

Comment: I made a fiddle, but it's not working at all.

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: yay version conflict! :-) ... I used angularjs 1.2.11 . I switched to 1.3.0beta7 and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

upgrading from angularjs 1.2.11 to 1.3.0-beta7 did the trick.